# Core Data NSFetchedResultsController sections

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, sections

How can I insert a section that doesn't exist in the database into the fetched results? 
I'd like to do what the iOS calendar app does. When there are no events for the current day, it still shows a section title.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this manually in your table view's data source / delegate.

If the fetched results controller doesn't have any sections, then return one from `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and the name or view for the section header from `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` or `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`.